# View dataframe while debugging in VS Code

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to explore switching from PyCharm to VS Code. I can't find a way right now to view my pandas DataFrames in a tabular format while debugging.

When I right click on a df object, there is no option to view.

I have the python extension downloaded. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: While this doesn't fix the issue, do note that typically you will want to view objects under the Debug Console tab the Variables view doesn't provide enough details.

Comment: Is there any better way to view the dataframe in vscode apart from Data Viewer option ?

Answer (score 137):

Microsoft VSCode team finally made this feature available with the January 2021 product update. More details could be found in [official blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-january-2021-release/#data-viewer-when-debugging)

As pointed out by @wisbucky, [Jupyter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) VSCode extension is prerequisite for this functionality.

It works like a charm and is very intuitive. In short:

1. Set up a break point (by clicking at the left most point of code area, before line number)
2. Start debugging (`Run` menu at top have `Start Debugging` option)
3. When debugger stops at the debug point, find the required dataframe inside `VARIABLES` panel. (`VARIABLES` panel is inside `Run and Debug` area)
4. Right click on dataframe and select option `View Value in Data Viewer`. TADA :)

Comment: They have removed it now.

Comment: *"They have removed it now".* No, the feature is still there in VS Code (May 2021) with Python extension (June 2021). Just make sure you are right clicking in the `Variables` panel. It doesn't work in any other panel such as `Watch` or the source code.

Comment: Another important note is that both Python and Jupyter vscode extensions must be installed for `View Value in Data Viewer` to appear. (The Data Viewer comes from the Jupyter extension.)

Comment: It's there only if on root variables. If there is an object, and it's argument is dataframe, it's not possible. You can dynamically create new variable and then display it.

Comment: One danger here: the data viewer will round small values (beneath 1e10, looks like) to 0. Printing the dataframe directly will show them as expected.

Comment: @wisbucky How to you make appear the `Variables` panel

Comment: There is no `View Value in Data Viewer` there. I am using Version: 1.62.0

Comment: @Julien, navigate to Run and Debug.

Comment: @wisbucky can you create an answer for your solution? Adding the Jupyter extension is the correct answer and it would be helpful for people who don't find your comment. I could do it myself but don't want to take the credit for your solution! :)

Comment: @Lazer OK, I created a separate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60097076/view-dataframe-while-debugging-in-vs-code/77490257#77490257

Answer (score 29):

You can now print the DataFrame in the DEBUG CONSOLE:

[image]

From the Github issue mentioned in [@Christina Zhou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60097498/2745495).

Answer (score 23):

My solution for viewing DataFrames in a tabular format while debugging is to simply copy and paste them into an Excel spreadsheet using

```
df.to_clipboard()
```

from the debug console. Even some of my colleagues running PyCharm are using this technique, since it gives you way more flexibility to inspect your data.

Comment: You are my new hero! Thank you

Comment: In vscode, I run `df.to_clipboard()` but paste option not available in debug console, am I missing something?

Answer (score 13):

It seems like currently you can do it only using the Jupyter notebook in VS Code, using the variables explorer.
[image: Jupyter Notebook in VScode - variables explorer]

Comment: This is also possible from .py files.

Answer (score 10):

So it looks like this isn't a thing right now in VS Code.

If anyone wants to show their support for the development of this feature, I found this open issue here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7063

Comment: Redirects to issue for Jupyter notebook on VS Code if you find something for VS Code and its python debugger, let us know.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1286#issuecomment-765059459

Answer (score 7):

you can use the view() function from xlwings library. It will show you the DataFrame in Excel:

```
import pandas as pd
from xlwings import view

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2], 'B':[3,4]})
view(df)
```

A better way would be to convert the function to pandas method:

```
from pandas.core.base import PandasObject
PandasObject.view = view
```

now you only need to type:

```
df.view()
```

Answer (score 2):

Install the Jupyter extension. This provides the `View Value in Data Viewer` features.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter

Answer (score 0):

Two more options for vscode are the following ones:

- [jupyter notebooks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks)
- saving to CSV and using the [edit csv extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=janisdd.vscode-edit-csv)

Both require more effort but the view is more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it if breakpoint is clunky:

command + shift + p (mac os)

'Jupyter: Open variables view' then click on the small two boxes with the arrow.

Personally, I find this easier and you could create a custom shortcut to bring  up the 'Jupyter: Open variables view' for speed

Answer (score -12):

The interactive shell looks like a good start.  Right click the .py file in your explorer. You'll be able to view pandas dataframes from there.

Comment: .. and then what? You seem to be missing a lot more details to make this an answer.