# How do I have DataFrame objects show up like a table in VSCode debug console?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I set a break point and started typing on the Debug Console. It seems to print a string representation of view of the object (a `pandas.DataFrame` in this casse). Is there anyway to have the object show up nicely like a table just like in iPython?

[image]

Here is my `launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Debug Console",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I am not a VS Code user, but there is an extension called "Prettify JSON" that may help. I am not sure.

Comment: @zhugen, thanks for the suggestion. My question is not really regarding `json` but pandas objects in debug. I included `launch.json`, which is a config file for VS Code, just in case it is that I made some mistake in the config.

Comment: Not exactly in the debug console but its now possible to get the dataframes in tabular format while in debug mode See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60097076/view-dataframe-while-debugging-in-vs-code