# Viewing numpy arrays and lists during debugging in an easier to read format

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've been making the switch over to VSCode lately, and have had quite a lot of success, I love the format. However, one thing I'm sorely missing is a good variable viewer for arrays and lists.
I am aware of the variable viewer that you can look at during debugging, however it's horribly and unnecessarily cluttered for lists and numpy arrays -having 4 sub folders- and you have to click into two of them to view the array laid out in a reasonable fashion. But with arrays wider than 4 you have to constantly scroll. Worse, while stepping through it will often close those subfolders and you have to reopen them again to continue watching!

Is there any way to view the array in a separate window that updates on its own (Yes I found the "data viewer" but you have to refresh it for it to update to any changes that have occurred to the array) like the way you can in Spyder or MATLAB?
Thanks!

Here's images of what I've found:

[image: This is the cluttered variable viewer I'm talking about]

This is the variable viewer I've already found, as you can see, it has all that cluttering with multiple folders I was talking about. I only need to see the values under the "0", "1", "2" subfolders because I need to watch them update as I step through my code.

[image: This is the data viewer I found]

I did find this data viewer, but it doesn't update as I step through the code, it has to be manually refreshed.

[image: Spyder Variable viewer]

Spyder has this variable viewer, which is the sort of thing that I'm looking for. It automatically updates as you step through your code and you can resize the variable slots (like you would adjust the size of a cell row/column in excel) to fit your needs

Comment: PyCharm has the functionality you're asking about built-in for numpy and pandas data structures (as well as matplotlib plots), but for VSCode the Data Viewer is the best way of doing so, that I'm aware of.

Comment: Have you tried clicking the plus button on the `watch` panel to add an expression?

Comment: And could you provide some pictures of the feature request you want the python extension to provide and what you are not satisfied with?

Comment: I did try that, but it keeps all the subfolder cluttering and it doesn't appear you can select just a subfolder, you have to put all those folders into the watch view. (If that's not the case please show me how.)
I've also updated it with the pictures you asked for. @Steven-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already found the outline view so I won't go over that.

Another way -
You could go to the debug console and output it to there.

Last way -
Right-click "Run Current File in Python Interactive Window" in the script, and select "Show variables active in jupyter kernel":

Comment: I like the idea of that last one and it appears to provide the needed functionality, but how do I enter step-by-step debugging in the new window?

Comment: It seems there is a nice solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65864298/11024270