# VSCode suddenly cant open dataframes in viewer

Tags: python, pandas

Looks like this issue has happened before with VSCode not able to display dataframe in the viewer.

This is my error:

```
Failed to create Data Viewer. Check the Jupyter of the Output window for more info.
```

The output window is empty and does not provide any error output.

This link here looks like the same issue but it was a while ago and I am seeing the same issue

[View dataframe while debugging in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60097076/view-dataframe-while-debugging-in-vs-code)

Steps have I done:

```
* Restarted VSCode
* Created a New Environment
* Restarted Jupyter 
* Moved from python 3.9.6 to 3.10.1
```

All the changes above did not fix my issue.
Here is my current VScode version:

```
Version: 1.63.2 (user setup)
Commit: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
Date: 2021-12-15T09:40:02.816Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042
```

OK Update to question. After several VSCode restarts and reinstalling Python. I was able to open Dataframes again on VSCode.

Looks like what breaks the dataframe viewer in VSCode is this script. Once I ran it, I could no longer open dataframes again. Looks like there is something I am doing wrong when I create this dataframe.

```
#-------
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# BeautifulSoup is imported with the name bas4 
#import bs4

URL = 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/1/year/2020'

# Fetch all the HTML source from the url
response = requests.get(URL)
dflnk = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Description','link']) 


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.select('a')

# Print out the result
for link in links:
  dlink = link.get_text()
  if link.get('href') != None:
    if 'https://' in link.get('href'):
      print(link.get('href'))
    else:
      hlink = 'https://www.espn.com' + link.get('href') # Convert relative URL to absolute URL
      
      if 'year' in link.get('href'):
          print(dlink)
          print(hlink)
          dict  = {'Description': dlink,'link': hlink}
          dflnk = dflnk.append(dict, ignore_index = True)
  print('----------------------------') # Just a line break
```

Basically I am trying to get all the links to all the scores on page.

Comment: Does it work with the simplest codes? And could you try to reinstall the `Python` and `Jupyter` extensions?

Comment: Yes, i cant open any dataframe. I wasing to to put a script I created for df but it didnt matter I cant open any df. Also I created a brand new python enviornment and installed jupyter on it same thing. Is that what you are asking. Also I am using Miniconda if that matters. Thanks for the feed back

Comment: No, I mean have you tried to reinstall the Jupyter Extension.

Comment: Hello Steven yes several times. I finally got VScode viewer to work. Then once I tried creating the dataframe above it broke the viewer again. This actually is better than an issue with VsCode.