# Use the data viewer for watch variables

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

It's very convenient when doing the debugging, we can select the watch variable and view the content as data viewer.

Usually, I have to go through the Variables tab and search for correct name of variable, and then right click to select "View as data viewer".

However, this process is time consuming and I really want to keep track particular variable inside the Watchs tab.

I don't see any feature of VSCode can handle that. Has any one found the solution. Thank you

[image]

Comment: This is the data science part in the official vscode tutorial. The jupyter notebook is used here, which already provides a good function of variable viewing. I don't understand what are you trying to achieve? jupyter and vscode debugging are not the same thing.

Comment: Usually, I am working with both Jupyter Notebook and Vscode Debugging.

Jupyter Notebook: Can view the dataframe by Data Viewer. 
VSCode Debugging: View the dataframe of VARIABLES only. Not in the WATCH. 

VSCode Debugging is suitable for project development. That's why I am using VSCode Debugging.

Comment: I haven't found anything similar so far, maybe you can go to GitHub and [submit this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose).

Comment: it seems to be that this feature did not exist in the VSCode Debugger. Btw, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this is to use the debug console (usually at the bottom close to the terminal tab) to evaluate your watch variable with some name. It will appear as a variable and you can right-click in "View Value in data viewer" as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60097076/view-dataframe-while-debugging-in-vs-code).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the effect of tracking variables in the **WATCH** panel? Here are my suggestions:

1. Select the `Run and Debug` icon to open the debug window,
2. select the `+` sign on the right side of the **WATCH** panel,
3. enter the name of the variable you want to trace, and it will always exist in the **WATCH** panel.

   [image]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Suppost that one variable x is a type of dataframe. I wanna to use the `Data Viewer` feature of VScode to view the content of variable x in WATCH.