# Debug console shows too much detail and too little data information

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

As the images below shows, the debug console shows too much information when you inspect a variable. Up untill recently, it showed all values when you inspected it, together with some general data like the min or max of the array. This is now impossible, as each dropdown menu has another dropdown menu seemingly ad infinitum.

[An example of the data I get to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/royYe.png)

I have tried following https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd/issues/1621 , but this only hides the special variables and function variables, while all other options remain and the overall data is still not available  (image 2). I have tried reinstalling and resetting VSCode ([How to reset settings in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code) second comment) , but to no avail. I am not sure what to try anymore.

Comment: what does the `VARIABLES` view of the debug bar show you

Comment: I think your problem may with Numpy and how it internally manages arrays/data, not with any change in the vscode debug console.

Comment: The same happens in the VARIABLES view, I can never view the actual data, just information about the data. Not what the second answer in this post shows (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60097076/view-dataframe-while-debugging-in-vs-code/60097498#60097498), although it used to be like that. 

In response to the second question, this happens to e.g. Pandas or other data structures too, it is not exclusive to Numpy.